# MVVM WPF listbox mouse leftclick event firing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I am building a WPF application with MVVM architecture. In one form I have 2 listboxes and I want to perform filter based search. I am using a common search textbox, so I have to differentiate the search based on which listbox is selected. Please find my sample listbox below:

```
<HeaderedContentControl Header="Visible Objects:" Height="120" Width="250" Margin="20,20,20,0">
    <ListBox Name="lstObjects" Height="100" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding ProfileObjTypeToBind, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Name="chkbxVisibleObjects" Grid.Column="1"
                          Content="{Binding Path=Value}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=flag,Mode=TwoWay}">
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</HeaderedContentControl>
<HeaderedContentControl Header="User Groups to View:" Height="120" Width="250" Margin="20,10,20,10">
    <ListBox Name="lstGroups" Height="100" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding ProfileUserGrpToBind, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Name="chkAllowedGroups" Content="{Binding Path=GroupName}" 
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=flag,Mode=TwoWay}">
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</HeaderedContentControl>
```

All I want to do is identify the listbox selected and perform the filtering based on text entered in textbox. Please help me

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: your sample is missing

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried so far? Including you XAML form and ViewModel.cs file, which I assume will be bound to that form.

Comment: Sorry, I had miss edited the code... please help

Comment: Please see my answers to the [Change combo box item list depending on the Textbox Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399423/change-combo-box-item-list-depending-on-the-textbox-text/20401850#20401850) and [Filtering DataGridView with two textboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530225/filtering-datagridview-with-two-textboxes/22532590#22532590) questions here on Stack Overflow for filtering examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a selected ListBox AND be able to write stuff to a TextBox. You can save the reference to your last ListBox though using SelectionChanged or some other method

```
private ListBox SelectedListBox = null;
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SelectedListBox = (sender as ListBox); 
}
```

once you have a reference to your last selected ListBox you can add TextChanged event to your TextBox:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (SelectedListBox == null)
        return;

    string searchText = (sender as TextBox).Text;
    SelectedListBox.Items.Filter = (i) => { return ((string)i).Contains(searchText); };  // Or any other condition required
}
```